# Bizarre CDStructures.h created by class-dump

Tags: c++, objective-c, class, assembly, struct

today I downloaded [*class-dump*](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) for getting information about the Mach-O files.
After *class-dump* created the header files of a sample application, I recognized a strange  `CDStructures.h` created by the tool.

There are lots of definitions of `struct`-objects, as expected. But some of them have no members, like this:

```
struct AlbumInfo;
....
struct ArtistInfo;
....
```

But other `struct`-objects use these empty objects like this:

```
struct RefPtr<sp::AlbumInfo> {
    struct AlbumInfo *_p;
};
```

Is that right? Or is there missing something? I find it strange that their are so many objects that have no members.
Another thing is that this `namespace` or whatever `sp` is not declared anywhere.

But the most strange thing I saw is that the elements inside of the angle brackets are on the one hand types (`sp::GuiControl*`) and on the other hand values (`64`, `true`).

```
struct Array<sp::GuiControl*, sp::GuiControl* const&, 64, true> {
    struct GuiControl **_field1;
    unsigned int _field2;
    unsigned int _field3;
};
```

Perhaps, you have already seen something like this and can help me. I don't know where I should start.
Is this just my fault or are there missing informations in the Mach-O files?

Comment: Those might be forward declarations. the fields of the structs may be in another file.

Comment: I searched for them but there are not any declarations of these structures.

Comment: Did you check all the files and not just headers?

Comment: I have no source files, it's a compiled application and with class-dump I created the header files from the Mach-O files.

Comment: Those are just forward declarations then and the fields data must be stored somewhere else.

Comment: I think they are in the __TEXT __const or __DATA __data segments. Is there a way to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class-dump` can only show you the structures for which the info is present in the executable's Objective-C metadata generated by the compiler. This usually includes any Objective-C classes and any structures they include as members (the Objective-C runtime needs to know their layout for the reflection/dynamic access to work). In the case of `struct AlbumInfo` or `struct GuiControl`, only *pointers* to them are present, and the size of the pointer is always the same regardless of what it points to, so there was no need to include the layout of the pointed-to structure.

`class-dump` included the forward declaration so that the code is syntactically correct, but it did not generate the actual struct layout since it was not present in the binary.

As for the angle brackets syntax, it's just C++ template instantiation. Again, the template declaration is not stored in the binary, but only the concrete instance of a template with all parameters specified.

Comment: So there is no chance to get a member list of `struct AlbumInfo` or `struct GuiControl`?

Comment: Well, there *is* a possibility that the info is there but class-dump could not find or interpret it for some reason, but I really doubt it. If the layout of those structures is not used in Objective-C classes, then it's pretty likely the necessary info has not been generated by the compiler. You will need to investigate the methods working with these structures to discover their layout.